# Do Autocutters for HVAC copper tubing exist?

Tags: hvac, cutting, copper-tubing

I have an 1/2" HVAC copper tube I need to cut in a tight space.  I see lots of 'autocutters' (the rounded cutting devices) for regular copper plumbing, which is measured by ID.  Do these cutters exist for copper tubing that is 1/2" OD, like HVAC tubing?  Can't seem to find any using my best google-fu.

Comment: Yes. Search for "copper pipe mini cutter 12.7 mm outside diameter" in your country

Comment: I use standard rigid cutters for my acr tubing and water pipe my smallest is ridgid 32975, I had to look it up but it will go 1/8-5/8 and that may be the square frame you are talking about but other than my 2 wheel cutter (way expensive) the mini ridgid cutter works great.

Answer (score 1):

I have some that are fixed 15mm and 22mm then I have two that are screw thread driven that work on ranges 6mm to 18mm and 10mm to 25mm.

Comment: These are doughnut-shaped, about diameter of a half-dollar.  I have screw-thread driven,  but they won't fit in the space.

Comment: Yes, my fixed ones are made by knipex I think but it is two halves which separate holding the rotating cutter and spring - took them apart a few months back for a quick clean. They also leave a nice rolled edge so the pipe goes into the fittings easily.

Comment: Are cuts in HVAC tubing supposed to be reamed out internally and deburred externally like tubing carrying water?

Comment: @JimStewart any pipe cut to fit a connection will need to have the edges deburred - standard practice and common sense. Any bits that could break off can cause expensive damage, it's all about doing the job properly.

Comment: How are you going to solder that joint or flair it depending on your coupler?

Comment: @Gil if you have a different question then ask your own. The OP was not asking about how to use couplers.

Comment: The OP has to cut tubing in a tight space. Can he ream and debur in this tight space?

Comment: @JimStewart why don’t you post your own answer and show tour expertees by solving all the problems?

Comment: @JimStewart y’a des bons, mais y’a toujours des cons.